# Infinity loop on Android application with BottomBar

Tags: android

I want to use the new bottom navigation pattern on my android application.

I found the library [BottomBar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) from roughike on Github.
My app should have four tabs and every tab should represent through a single activity. Therefore i had implement a `BaseActivity' which should handle the clicks.

The library has two callbacks

1. `onMenuTabSelected`and
2. `onMenuTabReSelected`.

Code:

```
 @Override
    public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {
        Intent intent = null;
        switch (menuItemId) {
            case R.id.menu_overview:
                intent = new Intent(this, OverviewActivity.class);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_transactions:
                intent = new Intent(this, TagsActivity.class);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_tags:
                intent = new Intent(this, TagsActivity.class);
                break;
        }

        if (intent != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Every time the application starts the `onTabSelected`method is called and the first case is executed. This will produce an infinity loop. My first tab is called every time...

Do anybody knows how i can handle with this problem?

Comment: can you either use a boolean to determine which activity is running and whether or not to run the onTabSelected method if it's the current activity, or pass the intent with a result in it for basically the same purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop occurs, if you set the OnMenuTabClickListener after you set the items for the bottom bar (mBottomBar.setItems(R.menu.bottombar)).

Just change the order and the loop will not occur.